# what is the correct way or what is the difference in using flow in composable

Tags: android, android-compose

```
In my viemodel I get from my RoomDB  a list of SmthObjects as StateFlow<List<SmthObject>>.
```

In my composable I use that list:

```
val listVM = viewmodel<MyViewModel>()
//var 1
val listVM = listVM.smthObjects.collectAsState()
val list = remember{
       **listVM**
}
```

and next I use this list in LazyColumn

but I cant do :

```
//var 2
val list = remember{
      **mutableStateOf(listVM.smthObjects)**
}

and use list as list.value.collectAsState().value
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: So, You just want to know how to get list object from flow then set to lazy column ?

Comment: I read that you need to use a state with REMEMBER. And I can write this in two ways. but I don’t understand how it will be right

Comment: from viewmodel I get StateFlow<List<SmthObject>> (corrected in question)

Comment: View models are created/assigned at the absolute top of the screen(on-screen level) and usually not passed to anything below - just values/callback lambdas. Using remember there could lead to weird behavior but I think in essence you can wrap `it val listVM by remember { viewmodel<MyViewModel>() }` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes doing [Google's Codelabs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-viewmodel-and-state) is worth the time it takes.

```
@Composable
fun GameScreen(
   gameViewModel: GameViewModel = viewModel()
) {
   // ...
}
```

Use `by`(delegate) and you don't have to call `.value`

```
val gameUiState by gameViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
```

In your case something like this:

```
val listVM = viewmodel<MyViewModel>()
val smthObjects by listVM.smthObjects.collectAsState()

LazyColumn {
    items(smthObjects) { smthObject ->
        // Your UI for the object
    }
}
```

Also, you don't want to hoist the state of the directly in the composable but in the view model itself.

```
class MyViewModel(private val roomDB: RoomDB): ViewModel() {

    val smthObjects: StateFlow<List<SmthObject>> = roomDB.loadSmthObjects()
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope, 
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000), 
            initialValue = emptyList()
        )
}
```

Comment: I read that you need to use a state with REMEMBER. And I can write this in two ways. but I don’t understand how it will be right

Comment: @СергейВ If you want the composable to hoist(hold and control) the state - yes. Then you should use `by remember { mutableStateOf() }`. but here view model is the "owner" of the state and Compose just collects it. If you meant view model then it should be initialized in the top composable for the given screen/route.

Comment: I mean that how to use  remember.  1)   val listVM = listVM.smthObjects.collectAsState()
val list = remember{
       listVM
}                                                                                                                                           or   2)    val listVM = viewmodel<MyViewModel>()   val list = remember{
      mutableStateOf(listVM.smthObjects)
}

Comment: @СергейВ You use `remember` when you don't want it to be touched/changed during recomposition. Your question will depend on what `listVM.smthObjects` is. If it is `smthObjects` from my example. You use **neither**.

Comment: from viewmodel I get StateFlow<List<SmthObject>>  (corrected in question)

Comment: should remember be used   directly on site or can be transferred to other composables?

Comment: @СергейВ `remember` doesn't change the type of variable or anything. It can be passed the same way as anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Use collectAsState() Directly in Composable:

```
@Composable

fun YourComposable() {
    val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel() // Get ViewModel

    // Collect the StateFlow as State
    val list = viewModel.smthObjects.collectAsState().value

    // Use the list in LazyColumn
    LazyColumn {
        items(list) { item ->
            // Display each item
        }
    }
}
```